# How to pass cli args in Slimerjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, slimerjs

I have a process in **Slimerjs** that I run through a **child_process** **Nodejs** and I need to pass it some arguments.

I know how to use cli args with Nodejs

```
var args = process.argv.slice(2);
```

And also with **Casper**

```
var casper = require("casper").create();

casper.echo("Casper CLI passed args:");
require("utils").dump(casper.cli.args);

casper.echo("Casper CLI passed options:");
require("utils").dump(casper.cli.options);

casper.exit();
```

However, I don't know how to use them in **Slimerjs**. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SlimerJS documentation is pretty vocal about using arguments: https://docs.slimerjs.org/current/api/system.html#args

```
var system = require('system')
var numberOfArg = system.args.length;
var thirdArgument = system.args[2];
```